# Choosing "a" or "an" before any digit beginning with 8

Tags: c++

```
int roll = RANDOM(1, 100);
printf("You rolled %s %d.", (roll == 8 ? "an" : ((roll > 79 && roll < 90) ? "an" : "a")));
```

Potential output:

```
You rolled a 12.
You rolled an 8.
You rolled an 84.
You rolled a 97.
```

The inline logic for determining an "a" or "an" for numbers starting with an 8 between 1 and 100 works fine.

1:  Is there a more elegant way to do this?

2: What's the best way to handle all integer value types that begin with 8?

Comment: One way to do this is to change the number to string, and then do pattern matching, like --> 8*, which will match all the patterns with 8 as starting.

Comment: How about an eighteen?

Comment: Anton Kovalenko and jwodder,  yes, I forgot about those!

Comment: Is it perhaps simpler to avoid the problem altogether by `printf( "You rolled %d.", roll )`? That is still perfectly correct (and arguably better) English - the use of the *indefinite article* is entirely superfluous.

Comment: Please consider modifying your accept to the (updated) [answer by @AlejandroDiaz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29450019/211160).  It's more generalized, clearly expressed, and a better solution in general to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `(roll == 8 || roll > 79 && roll < 90 ? "an" : "a")` is more concise, for starters.

You could have a solution based on a 2-character buffer `buf` and `snprintf(buf, 2, "%d", roll)`, but that seems overkill. And as pointed out in the comments, just looking at the first digit is not enough for total grammatical correctness, so it is better to stick with the disjunction of special cases.

Comment: Agreed, Pascal Cuoq.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Even more concise: `(roll == 8 || roll/10 == 8)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle all numbers starting with 8 something along the lines of this should do

```
bool startsWithEight(int number){
    while(number > 10){
        number /= 10;
    }
    return number == 8;
}
```

Might not be the most efficient way.

Comment: Better name: **startsWithEight**.  Also, that is a bit convoluted...why not start i at number and divide it as long as it's greater than 10?

Comment: @HostileFork you're right about the name, how is this more convoluted than doing that? Although that way I could save one extra division I guess, really this was just on the top of my head

Comment: Well, I think any time you've got a `for` loop with no content it's a little tricky to take in.  I also don't recommend not initializing variables at point of declaration.  Even as is, you could always say `int i = 10; while (i < number) { i *= 10;}` and I think it's more clear.  But if you thought this through from `int i = number;` you wouldn't be doing a multiplication and undoing it... it's just "twisty"